# Generic function with variable behavior depending on type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I need a generic function that changes its behavior depending on the variable type. My function has the form

```
void someFun<S> () {

    if( S == typeof(int) ) //<-- Here is the problem
    {
        //Some code
    }

    //Some other code
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `typeof(S)` as in `typeof(S) == typeof(int)`

Comment: Your method is no more generic when you do that. It is better not to have a generic method then.

Comment: The whole point of a generic method is that you do the **same** thing (more or less) for any type

Comment: Would it not be simpler to implement Extension metods per type if you wish to achieve this?

Comment: The thing is that the code in "some other code" has a lot of other type parametric functions, and the code looks cleaner if I just check for a special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use typeof for S too:

```
if(typeof(S) == typeof(int))
```

But rethink your assumptions. If a function has to alter behavior significantly for different types, perhaps it shouldn't be generic in the first place?